# d3 v4 values function going too far?

Tags: d3.js

Note: I have not yet been able to recreate this error outside of the project I am working on. Sorry in advance. I will continue to try and find a m.w.e. that reproduces this error.

I am currently using d3.values with map to transform some data, e.g.

```
d3.values(data).map(function(d, i) {return some_transformation})
```

for some reason, d3 is going beyond the array's index and using

```
function (){ return this[this.length - 1];} as the last index
```

e.g.

```
data = [{"x":1},{"x":3},{"x":3}]
d3.values(data).map(function(d, i) {console.log(i, d)})
```

returns

```
0 {"x":1}
1 {"x":2}
2 {"x":3}
3 function (){ return this[this.length - 1];}
```

Is there any ideas as to what might make this occur?

Comment: `.map()` is not any of D3's functions! `d3.values()` returns an array on which you call the native-JS method [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). That aside, I am afraid there is no help unless you are able to provide a runnable demo.

Comment: @altocumulus that actually explains the error... d3.values returns a list of the objects and then at the end the function! Why might d3.values do that?

Comment: It works for me as expected! Just like I said, you really need to provide a demo reproducing the error to get any help.

Comment: @altocumulus I am trying to recreate it, but I fear that it is something specific to my data's structure which is too large to provide (I have checked that it is valid JSON).

Comment: @altocumulus switching d3.values with Object.values fixes the error!

Comment: This shouldn't fix it, though! If it does, that would raise some serious concerns.

Comment: @altocumulus indeed it does. However, there is no denying the results

Comment: There is definitely more to `data` then is contained in the question. One possible source for trouble is the fact, that `d3.values()` is meant to be called on objects not arrays... But, even then, it's in your data, not in the function.

Comment: @altocumulus true. Although that statement wouldn't be clear from looking solely d3 examples which often has data be an array of objects.... Nonetheless if d3.values() is a wrapper for Object.values() getting different output is peculiar.